# Show that $(S,\ast)$ is associative if and only if $(T,\Box)$ is associative.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Assume that $(S,\ast)$ and $(T,\Box)$ are isomorphic binary strucutres.
>
> Show that $(S,\ast)$ is associative if and only if $(T,\Box)$ is associative.

Suppose that $(S,\ast)$ is associative and let $a,b,c \in T$. Since $f:(S,\ast) \to (T, \Box)$ is an isomorphism, it follows that $f^{-1}:(T,\Box) \to (S,\ast)$ is also.
Therefore $$\begin{align} f^{-1}((a \Box b) \Box c)& = (f^{-1}(a) \ast f^{-1}(b)) \ast f^{-1}(c) \\&=f^{-1}(a) \ast (f^{-1}(b) \ast f^{-1}(c)) \\&=f^{-1}(a \Box (b \Box c)).\end{align}$$ Applying $f$ to both sides of $f^{-1}((a \Box b) \Box c) = f^{-1}(a \Box (b \Box c)), $ we obtain $(a \Box b) \Box c = a \Box (b \Box c),$ proving that $(T, \Box)$ is associative. $\Box$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Yes. You also need to prove the if part, but it's analogous. An isomorphism between algebraic structures preserves any property that depends on the operation itself.

Comment: I thought that I didn't need to prove the converse, since stating that $f^{−1}:T \to S$ is an isomorphism proves the direct statement for every isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your proof is correct. Now all you need to do is show the converse in order to prove the biconditional.